# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException thrown by Munit Test case for a flow with a Reference Exception Strategy

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am trying to Run a Munit Test case for a flow which has a Reference Exception Strategy. But, i am getting the following exception.

Cannot resolve reference to bean 'Main_Choice_Exception_Strategy' while setting bean property 'exceptionListener'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'Main_Choice_Exception_Strategy' is defined (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException).

Please help resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot resolve reference to bean 'Main_Choice_Exception_Strategy' will occur when the test suite does not have import of the file which has the Main_Choice_Exception_Strategy. Adding the import of the file to the test suite will resolve the issue

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.